# Why are my events disappearing in iCal after upgrading to Lion and how can I fix it?

Tags: macos, ical, mobileme

I have several calendars synced using MobileMe and after upgrading to Lion it is often the case that a day's worth of newly added events all disappear. This generally happens when I am in another application. Often, if I re-add the same event later, the old events re-appear, giving me duplicates.  However, if I never re-add the events, the old ones never come back.

The events that are missing from my Mac still appear on my iPhone, but attempting to re-sync does not bring the events back to my Mac.

I have tried clearing my iCal cache and preferences while the events are missing, but this does not seem to bring them back.

So, why are my events disappearing in iCal and how can I fix it?

Comment: are you syncing your calendar to any other websites or services?

Comment: No, my Mac and iPhone are both only synching to mobile me. They are not even synching to each other via itunes, just mobile me.  Mac items sometimes disappear, iphone items do not.

Comment: Just to double-check, are all affected calendars within the 'ON MY MAC' group in the popover list of calendars?

Comment: Nope, they are all listed under the mobile me group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 5 and iCloud should be coming out tomorrow.  There should be improvements in this area.  Hopefully this will help you.  I know it is not what you would want to hear, but I have seen disappearing content like you describe.  Especially with Exchange, and OS 10.6.x

Comment: @rck I had similar problems with MobileMe, but can confirm with iCloud I have not seen these issues repeat. I have my iPhone, iPad and Mac syncing without any issues.

Comment: I'm hopeful the transition to icloud will fix it, but won't be testing it until after the bounty has expired, so I'm going to award it here and just hope it's right.

Comment: Well, it hasn't happened again since switching to iCloud, so I think this is over with.

Answer (score 0):

MacWorld just has an article: [How to make Lion's iCal less annoying](http://www.macworld.com/article/162218/2011/09/how_to_make_lions_ical_less_annoying.html), where the last Q&A is about the MobileMe sync on Lion's iCal, maybe can solve your problem.

Comment: This seems to be for enabling synching in general.  It will synch, it's just that sometimes (not every time) the items will disappear after they have been entered.  The interface for entering the events in the first place is iCal on the Mac, the same place that they are disappearing from.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem (except under Snow Leopard, so I don't think it's specific to Lion).  I asked about this on Apple's Support Communities but did not receive any useful responses.  However...

I use VPN (Cisco's VPNClient, specifically) to log into my employer's internal network.  I noticed that this dissappearing problem only happens to events that are added to iCal while VPN'd to work.  I suspect that something is being blocked when my Mac tries to sync with MobileMe.  Possibly the event is getting to MobileMe (which is why it shows up on my iPhone) but that a confirmation is not making it back through?  Now I only add events while not using VPN and the problem has not re-appeared.

Are you using VPN?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with BusyCal/Snow Leopard, and they tell me it is a known MobileMe bug. They didn't know whether iCloud would do better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, When you create an event on your iTouch or iPhone you must specify what calendar to use in the event setting. Depending on what calendar is synced with iCal that is the one you will choose.

Comment: That does not seem to be the issue, since events disappear and reoccur as duplicates.